# How to properly use a variable that is an array in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

so I have this form,

[image: form]

```js
var member_name = [];
$("input[type='text'][name='member[]']").each(function() {
  member_name.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(member_name);

var member_position = [];
$("input[type='text'][name='position[]']").each(function() {
  member_position.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(member_position);

var gender = [];
$("input[type='radio'][name='gender[]']:checked").each(function() {
  gender.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(gender)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="border: 1px solid #ddd;" id="table_member">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <th class="center">Name</th>
      <th class="center">Position</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="center">Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    // 1st row of the table
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <input type="text" name="member[1]" value="" />
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <input type="text" name="position[1]" value="" />
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <p class="center">
          <label>
                <input value="Male" name="gender[1]" type="radio" />
                <span>Male</span>
              </label>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <p class="center">
          <label>
                <input value="Female" name="gender[1]" type="radio" />
                <span>Female</span>
              </label>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    // 2nd row of the table


    <tr>
      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <input type="text" name="member[2]" value="" />
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <input type="text" name="position[2]" value="" />
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <p class="center">
          <label>
                <input value="Male" name="gender[2]" type="radio" />
                <span>Male</span>
              </label>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <p class="center">
          <label>
                <input value="Female" name="gender[2]" type="radio" />
                <span>Female</span>
              </label>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using jquery to get the data from the form and make it into an array because I will insert the data's to foreach loop.
This is my jquery,

All console.log returns "[]" that value. What is the problem? Please help. I'm still new at jquery so I'm sorry about my codes. But please help. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Problem:**

You're trying to select with names like `position[]/member[]/gender[]` when the names in your fields are like `position[index]/member[index]/gender[index]`.

**Suggested solutions:**

You could give your fields a common class, e.g: class `member` for all the fields with the name `member[index]` and so on for `position/gender`... then you can use simple selector by class.

If you don't want or you can't change the HTML structure I suggest the use of start-by selector `^=` in the name field instead like :

```js
var member_name = [];
$("input[type='text'][name^='member[']").each(function() {
  member_name.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(member_name);

var member_position = [];
$("input[type='text'][name^='position[']").each(function() {
  member_position.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(member_position);

var gender = [];
$("input[type='radio'][name^='gender[']:checked").each(function() {
  gender.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(gender);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="border: 1px solid #ddd;" id="table_member">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="center">Name</th>
      <th class="center">Position</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="center">Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    // 1st row of the table
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <input type="text" name="member[1]" value="member 1" />
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <input type="text" name="position[1]" value="position 1" />
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <p class="center">
          <label>
                <input value="Male" name="gender[1]" type="radio" checked/>
                <span>Male</span>
              </label>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <p class="center">
          <label>
                <input value="Female" name="gender[1]" type="radio" />
                <span>Female</span>
              </label>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    // 2nd row of the table


    <tr>
      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <input type="text" name="member[2]" value="member 2" />
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <input type="text" name="position[2]" value="position 2" />
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <p class="center">
          <label>
                <input value="Male" name="gender[2]" type="radio" />
                <span>Male</span>
              </label>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
        <p class="center">
          <label>
                <input value="Female" name="gender[2]" type="radio" checked/>
                <span>Female</span>
              </label>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi sir, I've tried that but I'm having syntax error.

Comment: Hi man, show me the error you get and review your code it may you're missing something (check the quotes...)

Comment: Heeeeeeey. I'm sorry my bad. I have extra brackets in my code. ANYWAYS! WAHHH YOU ARE MY FRIEND A LIFE SAVER. IT WORKED! T_T  Thank you so much. :)))))))

Comment: No worries, glad I could help brother.

Comment: Done. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Welcome anytime ;)